# Can't set a data attribute on HTMLScriptObject

Tags: javascript, jquery, stripe-payments

I have an HTMLScriptObject that I am trying to modify a data attribute. I need to calculate the data-amount and set that value which is used in the script but am having no luck. I have =the javascript working "correctly" (according to the final value in log), but I can't seem to be able to change the data-amount attribute in the markup below. Here is the relevant HTML markup:

```
<script src="/static/js/filename.js"></script>
<form action="" method="POST">
  <script id="stripe-button"
    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" 
    data-amount="0"
    ...
    >
  </script>
</form>
```

And here is the relevant filename.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( ".btn-service" ).click(function(){

        //add service price to the subtotal
        subtotalObj = $( "#subtotal" );
        price = parseInt($(this).data("price"));
        previousSubTotal = parseInt($( "#subtotal" ).text());

        if ($(this).hasClass( "btn-added" )) {
            nextSubTotal = previousSubTotal + price;
            $(this).text("Remove From Cart");
        }
        else if ($(this).hasClass( "btn-add" )) {
            nextSubTotal = previousSubTotal - price;
            $(this).text("Add To Cart");
        }

        //update the values
        subtotalObj.text(nextSubTotal);
        var stripe = document.getElementById('stripe-button');
        stripe.setAttribute('data-amount', nextSubTotal);
        console.log(stripe.getAttribute('data-amount')); //this returns the correct amount.
    });
});
```

The console log at the end of the data-amount property returns the value I'm looking for, but when I look at the markup source the data-amount value is still at 0. Not sure why the data-amount is not being changed.

I've tried also using the attr() method but JQuery puts out an error message: Object # has no method 'attr'. I've also tried using the data('amount', value) but that results in the same error - no method 'data'.

Comment: the jQuery errors are because `stripe` is a dom object reference, not a jQuery object... try `$(stripe).attr('data-amount', nextSubTotal)`... but your code should work fine see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Szy8V/1/

Comment: `parseInt($(this).data("price"));` is unnecessary, as jQuery already does that for you. Use `attr()` if you want to parse the int yourself.

Comment: @RobG I was talking about the last sentence -  `I've tried also using the attr() method but JQuery puts out an error message: Object # has no method 'attr'. I've also tried using the data('amount', value) but that results in the same error - no method 'data'.`

Comment: @awwester did you get this to work? I am trying the same thing and i can see the value in my console log but when I click on the stripe button it doesn't show me the value which was in console.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "in the markup " you mean using the browser's "view source" function, then you're looking at the page source, it isn't updated to reflect DOM changes (it's the source, not the current document).

Use a web inspector or debugger to see what the current DOM looks like as markup, or get the form's innerHTML property.

Also, you should declare all those variables with *var* to keep them local.

Comment: Thanks yes it was a combination of me looking at view source and a problem where the 3rd party tool is not seeing the updated value. Inspecting the element shows the correct value. Time to work with the 3rd party tool. Thanks.